# Input stack size=5000 error when using \include

Tags: latex, tikz

I am "including" a .tex file. I get the error "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].@nomath ...e@font@warning etc."
The error is located by latex in the line that says

> \pic[current plane, draw,fill=orange!50,fill opacity=.5, text
> opacity=1,"\footnotesize $\phi$", angle
> eccentricity=2.2]{angle=ketplus--origin--psiProjectedEquat}; %je
> nachdem, ob der Psi Pfeil links oder rechts von der z-Achse ist, muss
> man die Reihenfolge bei "angle=" umkehren   }

I should point out that the file that is "included" works when compiled on its own (where the preamble isn't in the masterfile but in the file itself. It seems that the `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` in the masterfile causes the problem.

MWE:

"file.tex":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc,math,angles,quotes}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
\usepackage{braket}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\include{file1}
\end{document}
```

"file1.tex":

```
\def\rotationSphere{-10} %Drehung im Uhrzeigersinn aus der Standardposition "x-Achse aus Bildebene heraus, y-Achse nach rechts"; 89.9 statt 90 (sonst Division von 0 durch 0)
\def\tiltSphere{10} %0.01 statt 0 da bei 0 Fehler bei der im Paket hinterlegten Rechnung mit Sinus/Cosinus kommen
\def\radiusSphere{2cm}
\def\psiTheta{70} %Winkel Theta
\def\psiPhi{65} %Winkel Phi

 %Farbeinstellung als Hinweis für sämtliche color= Befehle
  %draw={rgb,255:red,199; green,199; blue,199}

\begin{blochsphere}
[ball=none,radius=\radiusSphere,opacity=1,rotation=\rotationSphere,tilt=\tiltSphere,color=white]
    
\newcommand\drawLatitudeCircleNew[2][]{
\begingroup
\pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{sin(#2)*\blochsphere@radius}
\pgfmathsetmacro\radius{\blochsphere@radius*cos(#2)}
\drawCircleNew[#1,shift={{0,0,\yshift}},radius=\radius]{0}{0}
\endgroup
}%

\newcommand\drawLongitudeCircleNew[2][]{
\begingroup
\drawCircleNew[#1]{90}{#2+90}
\endgroup
}

\newcommand\drawCircleNew[3][]{
\begingroup
%\setkeys{blochsphere}{#1}
\setDrawingPlane{#2}{#3}
\computeVisibility{#2}{#3}{agamma}{abeta}
\begingroup\edef\tmp{\endgroup%
\noexpand\draw[opacity=0.2,line width=0.8,current plane,on layer=front,\unexpanded\expandafter{\blochsphere@style}] \unexpanded\expandafter{(\agamma-\abeta-0.2:\blochsphere@radius+\the\pgflinewidth*0.5) arc (\agamma-\abeta-0.2:\agamma+\abeta+0.2:\blochsphere@radius+\the\pgflinewidth*0.5)};
\noexpand\draw[current plane,opacity=0.5,line width=0.8,on layer=front,\unexpanded\expandafter{\blochsphere@style}] \unexpanded\expandafter{(\agamma+\abeta:\blochsphere@radius+\the\pgflinewidth*0.5) arc (\agamma+\abeta:\agamma-\abeta+360:\blochsphere@radius+\the\pgflinewidth*0.5)};
} \tmp
\endgroup
}%hier Dicke, Form und Farbe von Longitude/Latitude Circle einstellen
    
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{ball}{\pgfqpoint{-10bp}{10bp}}{
color(0bp)=(tikz@ball!90!white);
color(9bp)=(tikz@ball!90!white);
color(18bp)=(tikz@ball!90!white);
color(25bp)=(tikz@ball!90!black);
color(50bp)=(black)
}
\drawBall[ball=3d,radius=\radiusSphere,opacity=1,rotation=\rotationSphere,tilt=\tiltSphere,color=white]
     
      %\drawBallGrid[style={opacity=.3}]{30}{30}
  %Vertikale Ebene (als Kreis) zeichnen
  %\drawLongitudeCircle[]{\rotationSphere} 
  \drawLongitudeCircleNew[style={opacity=0.3,line width=0.8}]{-90-0} %Schreibe bei Befehle, die Latitude und Longitude verwenden immer {90-phiTheta} und {-90-phi)}
  %Horizontale Ebene (als Kreis) zeichnen
  \drawLatitudeCircleNew[style={opacity=0.3,line width=0.8}]{90-90} %style={dashed} falls Linie gestrichelt haben will

  %Punkte auf der Kugel definieren (für Achsen)
  \labelLatLon[radius=\radiusSphere*1.3]{ket0}{90-0}{-90-0}; %Schreibe bei LatLon Befehl immer {90-phiTheta} und {-90-phi)} wegen Definition von LabelLatLon
  \labelLatLon[radius=\radiusSphere]{ket1}{90-180}{-90-0};
  
  \labelLatLon[radius=\radiusSphere]{ketminus}{90-90}{-90-0+180};
  \labelLatLon[radius=\radiusSphere*2.2]{ketplus}{90-90}{-90-0};
  
  \labelLatLon[radius=\radiusSphere*1.25]{ketpluspi2}{90-90}{-90-90}; 
  \labelLatLon[radius=\radiusSphere]{ketplus3pi2}{90-90}{-90-90+180};
  \labelLatLon{psi}{90-\psiTheta}{-90-\psiPhi};
  
  %Achen zeichnen und markieren
  %z-Achse
  \draw[-latex,opacity=0.5,line width=0.8] (0,0,0) -- (ket0) node[below right,inner sep=.5mm,opacity=0.5] at (ket0) {\footnotesize $z$};
  %Bemerkung: 0,0,0 karthesische Koordinaten; ket0 in 2D Koordinaten auf der Kugeloberfläche
  %gepunkteter Teil der z-Achse
   \draw[-latex,opacity=0.3,line width=0.8,-] (0,0,0) -- (ketplus3pi2) node[below right,inner sep=.5mm,opacity=0.5] at (ketplus3pi2) {};
   %usw.
   \draw[-latex,opacity=0.3,line width=0.8,-] (0,0,0) -- (ket1) node[below right,inner sep=.5mm,opacity=0.5] at (ket1) {};
   \draw[-latex,opacity=0.3,line width=0.8,-] (0,0,0) -- (ketminus) node[below right,inner sep=.5mm,opacity=0.5] at (ket1) {};
  \draw[-latex,opacity=0.5,line width=0.8] (0,0,0) -- (ketplus) node[above left,inner sep=.5mm,opacity=0.5] at (ketplus) {\footnotesize$x$};
  \draw[-latex,opacity=0.5,line width=0.8] (0,0,0) -- (ketpluspi2) node[below left,inner sep=0.5mm,opacity=0.5] at (ketpluspi2) {\footnotesize $y$};
  %|psi> zeichnen
  \draw[-latex,color=orange,line width=2] (0,0,0) -- (psi) node[above]{\footnotesize $\ket{\psi}$};
  \def\phitest{65}
     \labelLatLon{test}{90-90}{-90-65};
  \draw[-latex,color=orange,line width=2] (0,0,0) -- (test) node[above]{\footnotesize $\ket{test}$};
  %Winkel zeichnen
  \coordinate (origin) at (0,0,0);
  {
     %Projektion zeichnen - cosinus verwendet
    \setDrawingPlane{0}{0}
    \draw[current plane,dashed] (0,0,0) -- (180+\psiPhi:{cos(90-\psiTheta)*\radiusSphere}) coordinate (psiProjectedEquat) -- (psi); %Winkel:Länge Polarkoordinaten
    %Winkel schattieren (phi)
    \pic[current plane, draw,fill=orange!50,fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1,"\footnotesize $\phi$", angle eccentricity=2.2]{angle=ketplus--origin--psiProjectedEquat}; %je nachdem, ob der Psi Pfeil links oder rechts von der z-Achse ist, muss man die Reihenfolge bei "angle=" umkehren
  }
  { \setLongitudinalDrawingPlane{-90-\psiPhi}
    %Winkel schattieren (theta)
    \pic[current plane, draw,fill=orange!50,fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1,"\footnotesize $\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5]{angle=ket0--origin--psi}; %je nachdem, ob der Psi Pfeil links oder rechts von der z-Achse ist, muss man die Reihenfolge bei "angle=" umkehren
  }  
\end{blochsphere}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, the combination of your tikz picture and babel causes the problem. You can fix this by loading the babel tikz library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc,math,angles,quotes}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
\usepackage{braket}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,babel}

\begin{document}
\include{file1}
\end{document}
```

[image]